Blazor server app DistributedCom error for {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} (Runtimebroker)
We have 2 Blazor server apps.  Occasionally, in the system log we see an error:

The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
and APPID
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}  to the user
MyDOMAIN\AccountName SID (S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx)
from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application
container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can
be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I think the CLSID in question refers to RunTimeBroker - C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe
I know it's my blazor server apps because the app pool identity mentioned in the error.  Why is my server app using runtimebroker.exe?
The app doesn't seem to be adversely affected when this error is logged, and I don't want to have grant the service account access because we manager many applications, and are in the process of migrating to blazor, and we don't want to have to do this for every application.

It seems that the error could be ignored:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/event-10016-logged-when-accessing-dcom?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5000693

@RuikaiFeng I agree, but they pollute the logs :)  I just don't want to have to explicitly grant my service accounts access to the component just to prevent the log entry,  because that would be onerous from a maintenance perspective
